# MongoDB Get Document Age in Hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am wondering if there is a way to get a MongoDB document age in hours? Here's what I have so far, but obviously I'm using a date object, it is not calculating the hours, and it's not giving the age, just the date it was created, so it is not giving the desired result. In fact, the $divide pipeline does not even allow for date objects. Any help is appreciated. Just as an FYI, the `$views` variable is a NumberInt32 type and the `$created_at` variable is a timestamp, like: `2014-05-20T00:01:08.629Z`.

```
db.projects.aggregate({ 
    $project: { 
        "result": {
            $divide: ['$views', '$created_at']
        }
    }
)
```

If you're wondering, this code is to help sort popular posts, but of course, it's only part of it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why can't you just use the created at date as part of the query? Match all docs created now minus two hours ago for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that `$views` and `$created_at` are fields in your document containing a number of views and the created timestamp as follows:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537abe5e8da9877dbb0ef604"),
    "views" : 5,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-05-20T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Then just a little date math getting the difference from the current time should do:

```js
db.projects.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "score": { "$divide": [
            { "$divide": [
                { "$subtract": [ 
                    new Date(), 
                    "$created_at" 
                ]},
                100*60*60
            ]},
            "$views"
        ]},
        "created_at": 1,
        "views": 1
    }}
])
```

So you are basically getting the difference in hours from the current time as a date object and the `created_at` value. Dividing that by a standard number for hours in a day, then dividing by your `views` in order to get your "score" result for sorting.

When you do math operations with **two** date objects then the result is returned as a number. So further operations with just numbers will work from then on.

Comment: You're awesome, man! I'll test this code tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Works great, man! There was an issue with the score getting smaller as the `views` value increased, but that was fixed by changing it so the `$views` value would be divided by the age, instead of the other way around.